# alert box through validation

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Is it possible with cakePHP 2.0 to have a field validated based on two other fields and still allow the user to go through with the submit?

Something like this, I have a form that has rate, term and credit tier. The rate is usually based on the term and credit tier like this, a credit tier of B and a term of 60 months will have a rate of 6.75%. But there will be instances where I want to have a rate of 5.25% for this same tier and term.  Is there a way to alert the user that the rate does not match the tier and term combination but still allow the user to submit the rate the way it is?  The rate, term, and tier will be stored in the database so that it can easily be changed as rates change.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - in your model, [define your own validation method](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods) and crunch your numbers in there.  It might be better to pass your data in with `$this->Form->hidden()` than call other models while validating.